# User Activation Fails. $_GET no working

Tags: php

http://www.prise.tk/activate.php?x=roshnihi%40gmail.com&y=a588e697aac7814486ef589242ac8dbb

Above is my activation url which is sent to the new user who is trying to register. But the value of x and y are no getting fetched by `$_GET` in my `activate.php` code.

Below is my snippet from the code :

```
//Validate $_GET['x'] &  $_GET['y'] 
$x = $y = FALSE;

if(isset($_GET['x']) && preg_match('/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}&/', $_GET['x'])){  
    $x = $_GET['x'];

}


if(isset($_GET['y']) && (strlen($_GET['y']) == 32 )){
    $y = $_GET['y'];
}


if($x && $y){    //Update Database
echo 'connected';
    require('../db.php'); 

    $q = "UPDATE dealers SET active=NULL WHERE (email='". mysqli_real_escape_string($handle, $x) . "' AND active='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($handle, $y) . "') LIMIT 1"; 
    $r = mysqli_query($handle, $q) or trigger_error("Query : $q\n<br>MySql Error:" . mysqli_error($handle));

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($handle) == 1){
        echo "<h3> Your account is now active. You may now log in.</h3>";
    }


AND below is my register.php code:

  $a = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));  // Create activation code

           $q = "INSERT INTO dealers (fname, lname, email, password, address, pincode, active) VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$e','$p','$add','$pin','$a')";
           $r = mysqli_query ($handle,$q) or trigger_error("Query : $q\n<br>MySql Error:" . mysqli_error($handle));   //Run the query

           if(mysqli_affected_rows($handle) == 1){  // if query ran ok

                // Send Mail 
                $body = "Thankyou for registering. To activate, please click on the link:\n\n";
                $body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x='. urlencode($e)  . "&y=$a" ;

                mail($trimmed['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: xxx@gmail.com' );
```

Comment: decode $_GET['x'] and then use preg match... preg match return false as email id is encoded and does not contain @

Comment: can you please give me the exact syntax of the code? @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: change your pregmatch  as : `preg_match('/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}&/', urldecode($GET['x']))`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI your code is missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: Still not working :(
Also  read online that $_GET automatically decode an encoded mail. Anyhow, I changed the code as per your suggestion. But still no result. :/

Comment: @Shadow Can you also help?

Comment: @marc_s  I'm stuck in this code for way too long. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fetch first and check second. Here, check for existance of x and y, e.g.

```
$x = (isset($_GET['x'])) ? urldecode($_GET['x']) : NULL;
```

Then check if x has a valid email address format, e.g.

```
if(filter_var($x, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
    .. code ..
}
```

The length check is somewhat uncalled-for since you should check if the key exists in you DB table. Otherwise, the only validity check is the length. One could easy fake a 32-character key to enable the accounts of persons he knows the email address of. Not a real danger, but still a security "mishap" imho.

I reproduced your code locally and it worked fine. Hope this helps.

Tip: try to accomodate yourself with PDO or at least the object-oriented style ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)). It's the future. :)

Comment: Thankyou sooo much! It worked just fine :)
And yes, i will definitely try to implement PDO and OOPS.